# Alfa card scans networks for a few mins and only when replugging it into USB port

Tags: networking, kali-linux

I am running Kali Linux (2020.1b 64bit) via VirtualBox (6.1) on a macOS host (10.15.4) with a brand new Alfa AWUS036NH network card attached via USB.

The network card is recognised by Kali Linux and is set to monitoring mode:

```
$ iwconfig                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
lo        no wireless extensions.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  Mode:Monitor  Frequency:2.427 GHz  Tx-Power=20 dBm                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
          Retry short  long limit:2   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
          Power Management:off
```

However, when running `airodump-ng wlan0`, no wireless networks are discovered despite there being numerous.

I have noticed that by physically removing the adapter and re-plugging it back into the USB port, I am able to get the card to discover the nearby networks. This does not always work, but it is the only scenario that I am able to get it working. Furthermore, whenever I get it "working", this state is short-lived and the networks disappear within a few minutes -- and then silence.

What could be causing this unusual behaviour and what diagnostic tests can I run to narrow down the cause?

Comment: Have you ensured other programs aren't changing the wireless channel? How are you setting it to monitor mode?

Comment: This is not sounding like a security problem but a hardware problem.

Comment: @multithr3at3d It's a fresh install of Kali Linux and I am following a tutorial that uses the exact same setup (well, only minor differences in software/OS versions) and the exact same alfa wireless card, so I wouldn't have thought so. The card seemed to be in monitor mode by default. However, I also ran `ifconfig wlan0 down` `iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor` `ifconfig wlan0 up`, which should ensure it is monitor mode, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: @josh, any reason you aren't using airmon-ng to put it in monitor mode? You should have a wlan0mon Interface created when it's actually in monitor mode. You can rule out the setup by live booting from a kali USB, and making sure the adapter isn't defective. If it works live booted, you know something isn't configured correctly in the VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of this problem lies with VirtualBox. Though I have not been able to pinpoint the exact cause, I was able to get the card working perfectly by running Kali directly off the machine with live booting. There were no other changes necessary (i.e. same commands, same software/os versions, same hardware, etc).